# How to create listview with button from inside python and with button press event in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I want a simple example for creating listview with button from inside python and with key press event in kivy.

Like this
[image]

I have one other conceptual question regarding ListView button and an ordinary button.

I made multiple ordinary buttons in a page which looks and feel similar to listview buton. My question is which is computationlly better multiple ordinary buttons or a listview?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use ListView instead of RecycleView?

Comment: I am new to kivy and I dont know anything about recycleview or its usage. Is it similar to what I want?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.listview.html) ListView is being deprecated in favor of RecycleView .